# remove a character or characters from each line

Tags: php, regex

can any one help me to solve this issue.
 problem with '>' symbol
When emails are forwarded, some email clients will add “>” symbols before each line of the email. For example:

```
This is an example of forwarded text
```

Becomes:

```
> test message
```

If this is done many times, text can become unreadable:

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> test message
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> test message
```

There may even be spaces in between groups of “>” symbols, like this:

```
>> >>>>>> >>>>>>>>> test message
```

i need to remove these text from each line and clean the email content

anyone help me to find out a regular expression to fix this issue

Comment: i just tried to copy the content to a text area and while pressing convert ,i need to get the new content with out '>' symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function strip_forward($input) {
    return preg_replace("/^[> ]+/m","",$input); 
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////

$input = ">>> >> > Test\n".
         ">> Test\n".
         "> Test\n".
         "Test";

echo $input."\n\n\n";
echo strip_forward($input);
```

Test it here: http://codepad.org/I1Ddfwte

Answer (score 2):

$trimmed = preg_replace( '/^([>\s]+)/m', '',  $content );

Comment: You made it better and before than me! :) +1

Comment: It will only replace the first occurrence. You need the /g modifier to replace all of them

Comment: In PHP the g modifier is not allowed. In this case is also not necessary because each line will be considered separately.

Comment: [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) allows a limit argument which defaults to no limit.

Comment: It works for my  dummy text. Please supply the input where it's not working.